# How to send contsructor parameters from one class to another?

Tags: java

So I wouldn't say I'm new to java, but I've forgotten quite a bit since I've last coded. As such, I was wondering if it was at all possible to send a constructor's parameters from one class to another. I assumed I had to make an object of the constructor from "class B" in "class A". However, there are multiple constructors in my second class, and unless I can figure out how to send parameters over, I'm stuck with a constructor I don't want to use. Here's a snippet of my code.

```
public class Title{
/* Title packet */
private Class<?> packetTitle;
/* Title packet actions ENUM */
private Class<?> packetActions;
/* Chat serializer */
private Class<?> nmsChatSerializer;
private Class<?> chatBaseComponent;
/* Title text and color */
private String title = "Falling Maze";
private ChatColor titleColor = ChatColor.GREEN;
/* Subtitle text and color */
private String subtitle = "Tip: Fall through the maze to win! You may only touch sandstone!";
private ChatColor subtitleColor = ChatColor.RED;
/* Title timings */
private int fadeInTime = 10;
private int stayTime = 20;
private int fadeOutTime = 20;
private boolean ticks = true;
private static final Map<Class<?>, Class<?>> CORRESPONDING_TYPES = new HashMap<>();

/**
 * Create a new 1.8 title
 *
 * @param title
 *            Title
 */
public Title(String title) {
    this.title = title;
    loadClasses();
}

/**
 * Create a new blank title.
 */
public Title() {
    this("");
}

/**
 * Create a new 1.8 title
 *
 * @param title
 *            Title text
 * @param subtitle
 *            Subtitle text
 */
public Title(String title, String subtitle) {
    this.title = title;
    this.subtitle = subtitle;
    loadClasses();
}

/**
 * Copy 1.8 title
 *
 * @param title
 *            Title
 */
public Title(Title title) {
    // Copy title
    this.title = title.title;
    subtitle = title.subtitle;
    titleColor = title.titleColor;
    subtitleColor = title.subtitleColor;
    fadeInTime = title.fadeInTime;
    fadeOutTime = title.fadeOutTime;
    stayTime = title.stayTime;
    ticks = title.ticks;
    loadClasses();
}

/**
 * Create a new 1.8 title
 *
 * @param title
 *            Title text
 * @param subtitle
 *            Subtitle text
 * @param fadeInTime
 *            Fade in time
 * @param stayTime
 *            Stay on screen time
 * @param fadeOutTime
 *            Fade out time
 */
public Title(String title, String subtitle, int fadeInTime, int stayTime, int fadeOutTime) {
    this.title = title;
    this.subtitle = subtitle;
    this.fadeInTime = fadeInTime;
    this.stayTime = stayTime;
    this.fadeOutTime = fadeOutTime;
    loadClasses();
}
```

This is my class with all the different constructors used for different types of titles. What I want to do is be able to create a title with a title, subtitle, fadeInTime, stayTime, and fadeOutTime and call it in my other class placed below.

```
public class Main extends JavaPlugin implements Listener{

private Title t1 = new Title();

public void onEnable()
{
    Bukkit.getPluginManager().registerEvents(this, this);

}
@EventHandler
public void playerJoin(PlayerJoinEvent event)
{
    //getting the player's name
    Player player = event.getPlayer();
    //adding the gold ingot and the bed to their respective inventory slots.
    ItemStack bed = new ItemStack(Material.BED);
    ItemStack goldIngot = new ItemStack(Material.GOLD_INGOT);
    player.getInventory().setItem(0, goldIngot);
    player.getInventory().setItem(8, bed);
    t1.send(player);
}
```

when I created the object of my Title class all it did was bring over my first constructor(the one that creates a blank title). What I would like for it to bring over is the ability to create a full title with, like I said before, a title, subtitle, fadeInTime, stayTime, and fadeOutTime. Any help would be much appreciated, because when I try to pass the parameters over to my new object Title() it says the parameters cannot be resolved to a variable.Thank you in advance. I tried to be as specific as possible, but ask me anything that would help and I'll answer to the best of my abilities.

Big props to Andreas for helping me figure it out. turns out that my title was being overwritten no matter what, so I set up a for loop in my Main class that would send a timer as my title. That enabled my to pull from the other class. Thank you so much! ^-^ Is there a way to upvote your comment?

Comment: "bring over"? If you can access one (public) constructor, you should be able to access all of them. Are you sure you imported the correct Title class in the second snippet?

Comment: like @Kerstomaat said you should be able to access the other constructors

Comment: @kerstomaat are you saying I didn't import the correct title class, or constructor? I did in fact import the correct class, because when I created my object and hovered over the constructor of the new object it gave me the use of the class, which is creating a new blank title. I don't want that one is what I mean. I would like the one that creates a title, subtitle, fadeInTime, stayTime, and fadeOutTime.

Comment: So what's stopping you from writing `private Title t1 = new Title("My title", "My subtitle", 2, 5, 2);`?

Comment: @Andreas I could do that I suppose, but I would've liked to have brought over my title, subtitle, etc from my Title class instead of creating new variables in my Main class.

Comment: Brought over what values? From where? I was talking about *changing* the line you already have.

Comment: Yes, but that would mean I'd have to send it those values correct? Instead of sending it the values I have in my title class.

Comment: If you want the value `"Falling Maze"` to be retained, you need a constructor that *doesn't replace it!* All of your constructors *replace* the value of `title`, so the default assigned value is *always discarded*.

Comment: It's called encapsulation in your Title class.  Use getters and setters to set sub titles, fade-in and fade-out timers.  Then you can do stuff like t1.setSubTitle("")

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty not sure what are you asking for, but .. If you need to pass value from input parameter from 1st constructor to the 2nd class constructor, you can do it simply.
Check the pseudocode bellow:

Let you have 2 classes (let me say `ClassA` and `ClassB`), both of them will have 1 string parameter in constructor, and the second class will also have one integer input parameter, so it will look like this:

```
class ClassA{
      /*that will be variable of each instance of that class
      * when public, can call something like 
      * classAinstance.classInstanceVariableA, otherwise you have to make getter for reading and setter for setting
      */
      String classInstanceVariableA;

      //that is the constructor
      ClassA(String paramStr){
         //..whatever, eg.
         this.classInstanceVariableA = paramStr;
      }

     //getter example
     public String getClassInstanceVariableA(){
        return classInstanceVariableA;
     }

    //setter example
     public void setClassInstanceVariableA(String value){
         this.classInstanceVariableA = value;
     }
}

class ClassB{
    ClassA classBinstanceVariableOfClassAType;
    int classBintVarInstance;

    ClassB(String classBparamConstructor, int param2intConstructor){
        //there you can call construtor from the ClassA eg.- that you mean?!?
        this.classBinstanceVariableOfClassAType = new ClassA(classBparamConstructor);
        this.classBintVarInstance = param2intConstructor;

        //when public parameter classInstanceVariableA
           //read value this.classBintVarInstance.classInstanceVariableA
           //set value this.classBintVarInstance.classInstanceVariableA = "foo"
       //when not public and you have getter and setter
           //read value this.classBintVarInstance.getClassInstanceVariableA();
           //set value this.classBintVarInstance.setClassInstanceVariableA("foo");
    }
}
```

Please notice, you cant to call something like `classBinstance.classBinstanceVariableOfClassAType` **until it is public or you have again the getter** there, you can also make a method to return mentioned string variable from `classA` in `classB`, clear?